# add ttf font subtitles and attachments in MKV using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am wanting to add ASS subtitles and TTF font attachments to an MKV file using ffmpeg.

for subtitles i'm using this code and it works normal

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i subtitle.ass -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -scodec ass -metadata:s:s:0 language=English movie_final.mkv
```

And for TTF attachments I am using this.  It even adds the attachments but then in the player the fonts are not recognized

```
ffmpeg -i movie_final.mkv -map 0 -map 1  -c copy -attach "font.otf" -metadata:s:   mimetype=application/x-truetype-font movie.mkv
```

Any other code that does this?  I don't have access to Mkvmerge

thanks